# Imagem Responsive HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Alguém pode me ajudar! Não estou conseguindo deixar as imagens responsivas via CSS e também em bootstrap. Estou utilizando o banner-rotator-2.source com jquery, onde tentei definir a class="img-responsive"; style="width:100%"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Em bootstrap adicione a **class** **img-responsive**

```
<img src="cinqueterre.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
```

Essa class vai aplicar **max-width: 100%, height: auto,** e **display:block** à imagem